# Jquery var and hide very fast

Tags: jquery, settimeout

I created this function to show a popup and close after some time:

```
function alerta(ancho,alto,color,tiempo_s,tiempo,contenido) {
    $("#alert_background").show();
    $("#alert_window").show(1000);
    $("#alert_window").css("width",""+ancho);
    $("#alert_window").css("height",""+alto);
    $("#alert_window").css("background-color",""+color);
    $("#alert_window").append(""+contenido);

    if(tiempo!="") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#alert_background").hide(tiempo);
            $("#alert_window").hide(tiempo);
        }, tiempo_s);
    }
}

alerta("40%","200px","green","4000","3000","<b>Hello World!!!</b>")
```

The only problem I have is in this function in the:

```
$("#alert_background").hide(tiempo);
$("#alert_window").hide(tiempo);
```

The `div`s close very fast and no respect the time for close. I use `setTimeout(function())` because I need to show this div for some time and hide the 2 `div`s afterwards. Instead, the `div`s hide in 3 or 4 seconds.

Comment: time in ms should be a number, not a string.

Comment: Try passing in a int instead of a string into your `alerta` function. `alerta("40%","200px","green",4000,"3000","<b>Hello World!!!</b>")`

Comment: i do that but the time for hide no respect

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
function alerta(ancho,alto,color,timeOut,durationFadeOut,content) {
    $("#alert_background").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#alert_window").fadeIn(1000);
    $("#alert_window").css("width",ancho);
    $("#alert_window").css("height",alto);
    $("#alert_window").css("background-color",color);
    $("#alert_window").html(content);

    setTimeout(function(){
               $("#alert_background").fadeOut(durationFadeOut);
                $("#alert_window").fadeOut(durationFadeOut);
            }, timeOut);

}
```

Here is the demo

http://jsfiddle.net/5XQkY/32/